# Access nested JSON values using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to access a nested JSON value using Python.

Here is an excerpt of my JSON:

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "page_video_views",
      "period": "day",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 634,
          "end_time": "2018-11-23T08:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
          "value": 465,
          "end_time": "2018-11-24T08:00:00+0000"
        }
      ],
      "title": "Daily Total Video Views",
      "description": "Daily: Total number of times videos have been viewed for more than 3 seconds. (Total Count)",
      "id": "{page-id}/insights/page_video_views/day"
    },
```

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
import json
import urllib.request

data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/{page-id}/insights?access_token={access-token}&pretty=0&metric=page_impressions%2cpage_engaged_users%2cpage_fans%2cpage_video_views%2cpage_posts_impressions").read()

output = json.loads(data)

print(json.dumps(output, indent=2))

for item in output['data']:
    name = item['name']
    period = item['period']
    value = item['data']['values']['value']

    print(name, period, value)
```

The issue I am facing is that whenever I run the code to access 'name' and 'period' it works beautifully, but I cannot access 'value' in 'values'. I believe this is because there are two 'value' results, and I would like to pull the first one each time.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`item['data']['values']` is a list. You need to get its first element and only then access its `'value'` field. That is, the corresponding line should be:

```
value = item['data']['values'][0]['value']
```

Comment: You're the master my friend. It actually worked on `value = item['values'][0]['value']`

Comment: Remember to accept his answer so other people can see that this is what solves the problem! ;)

Comment: Sorry about that! It was answered within 9 minutes so I had to wait and got a little distracted.