# How do I access JSON elements with urllib and Python3

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I'm trying to access an API via urllib in Python3.  The API is here:

https://api.zxinfo.dk/doc/#!/zxinfo/getGameById

The used a script I found here which prints the JSON dump OK, but when I try and access individual values I get the error 'KeyError: controls'

[Access nested JSON values using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492603/access-nested-json-values-using-python)

How do I access the individual elements?

I have spent today looking at various other questions but I can't get to the bottom of it.

Thanks in advance.

```
import json
import urllib.request

data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.zxinfo.dk/api/zxinfo/games/0001551?mode=compact".read().decode('utf8')

output = json.loads(data)

print(json.dumps(output, indent=2))

for item in output ['controls']:
        title=item ['control']
        print(title)
```

Comment: Looks like you have a '_source' key you're not taking care of, I.e. output['_source']['controls']

Comment: Wow, thank you. That's it.  Amazing!

Comment: @jonto That worked thank you, but if I try and add the fulltitle as well with:
`for item in output['_source']:
        title=item['fulltitle']
        print (title)' I get string indices must be integers