# Checking if value in json file is equal to python variable

Tags: python, json, variables

I am trying to check if a specific item in a json file is equal to one of my python variables.

```json
{'data': {'redemption': {'channel_id': 'secret',
                         'id': 'secret',
                         'redeemed_at': '2021-02-08T09:46:22.637059711Z',
                         'reward': {'background_color': '#FA1ED2',
                                    'channel_id': '145998001',
                                    'cooldown_expires_at': None,
                                    'cost': 500,
                                    'default_image': {'url_1x': 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/custom-reward-images/ghost-1.png',
                                                      'url_2x': 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/custom-reward-images/ghost-2.png',
                                                      'url_4x': 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/custom-reward-images/ghost-4.png'},
                                    'global_cooldown': {'global_cooldown_seconds': 1,
                                                        'is_enabled': False},
                                    'id': '123',
                                    'image': None,
                                    'is_enabled': True,
                                    'is_in_stock': True,
                                    'is_paused': False,
                                    'is_sub_only': False,
                                    'is_user_input_required': False,
                                    'max_per_stream': {'is_enabled': False,
                                                       'max_per_stream': 1},
                                    'max_per_user_per_stream': {'is_enabled': False,
                                                                'max_per_user_per_stream': 1},
                                    'prompt': '*Dabs*',
                                    'redemptions_redeemed_current_stream': None,
                                    'should_redemptions_skip_request_queue': False,
                                    'template_id': 'template:4425c37e-6881-442a-aa3d-fdc6998a29de',
                                    'title': 'Dab!',
                                    'updated_for_indicator_at': '2020-09-10T18:55:40.064177881Z'},
                         'status': 'UNFULFILLED',
                         'user': {'display_name': 'Androteex',
                                  'id': 'secret',
                                  'login': 'androteex'}},
          'timestamp': '2021-02-08T09:46:22.637059711Z'},
 'type': 'reward-redeemed'}
```

I want to find the second id: `'id': '123'` and check if id is equal to 123. And if so I want to print that string. How could I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492603/access-nested-json-values-using-python

Comment: what does the `[0]` do? @fernand0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JSON module.

```
import json

data = json.loads(my_json)
my_id = data['data']['redemption']['reward']['id']
if my_id == '123':
    print(data)
```

Comment: although maybe not use id as the var name since its a built in function `<built-in function id>`

Answer (score 0):

Granted it was added to data (can be done with `json.loads`):

```py
id = data['data']['redemption']['reward']['id']
idcheck = 123
if (int(id) == idcheck):
    print ("YES")
```